# How to unlock location and rotation of multiple objects at once?

Tags: python

Actually i have found the solution and wanted to share this cool python script to do this.

```
import bpy

COLLECTION_NAME = "Collection 1"

for collection in bpy.data.collections:
    if collection.name == COLLECTION_NAME:
        for obj in collection.all_objects:
            for i in range(len(obj.lock_location)):
                obj.lock_location[i] = False
                obj.lock_rotation[i] = False
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. While answering your own question is possible and even encouraged, it should be done respecting the site structure. Could you break this up into two posts, rephrasing the problem to read like an actual question or expose a problem, while the solution is written as separate answer in the proper section below? Maybe add a short description of the steps accompanied by a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating the workflow and final results. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 2):

Easy solution for you:

Select all objects, unlock and select from context menu:

- "Copy all to selected" (for all X Y Z axis)
- "Copy single to selected" (For X, Y or Z specifically)

As you see, python is not required for such easy tasks.

[image]

BTW, you can copy every value, related to multiple objects, using this menu. From object locations to rigid body settings